# Picasso only loading single image but the size is 20

Tags: android, web-services, picasso, retrofit2, image-loading

I am trying to make a service call with Retrofit and RxJava. I am using Picasso 2.5.2 to upload image from the API call. I am getting the image displayed, but i am getting single image only. When I debug, I get size as 20 but the displayed is single. Any help on that would be great.

The Adapter class:

```
public class PopularMoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularMoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> {

private final String TAG = PopularMoviesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;
private List<MoviesResponse> movieItems = new ArrayList<>();

public PopularMoviesAdapter(Context context, List<MoviesResponse> movieItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movies_grid_item, parent, false);
    return new MoviesViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    List<Movies> movies = movieItems.get(position).getResults();
    String imageUrl = IntentKeys.MOVIES_POSTER_ENDPOINT + movies.get(position).getPosterPath();
    Log.d(TAG, "Poster URL from the API call: " + imageUrl);
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
    Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

    public MoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movies_grid_item_image);
    }
}}
```

The fragment class:

```
    public class PopularMoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 2;
    private List<MoviesResponse> responses;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PopularMoviesAdapter popularMoviesAdapter;
    private Subscription subscription;
    private MoviesService service = RetrofitManager.getMoviesClient().create(MoviesService.class);

    public PopularMoviesFragment() {
        responses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_movies, container, false);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(
                getActivity(),
                COLUMN_COUNT,
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.popular_movies_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(COLUMN_COUNT, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        return view;
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getMoviesSubscription();
    }

    private void getMoviesSubscription() {
        subscription = service.getPopularMovies(IntentKeys.POPULAR_MOVIES_API_KEY)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        new Action1<MoviesResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(MoviesResponse movies) {
                                responses.add(movies);
                            }
                        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Throwable throwable) {

                            }
                        }, new Action0() {
                            @Override
                            public void call() {
                                displayPosters();
                            }
                        }
                );
    }

    private void displayPosters() {
        popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), responses);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter);
        recyclerView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (subscription != null && subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

}
```

Finally the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/movies_grid_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movies_grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

POJO:

```
  public class Movies implements Serializable {

    private String posterPath;
    private Boolean adult;
    private String overview;
    private String releaseDate;
    private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Integer id;
    private String originalTitle;
    private String originalLanguage;
    private String title;
    private String backdropPath;
    private Float popularity;
    private Integer voteCount;
    private Boolean video;
    private Float voteAverage;

    // getters and setters ommitted and constructor
}


   public class MoviesResponse implements Serializable {
    private Integer page;
    private List<Movies> results = new ArrayList<Movies>();
    private Integer totalResults;
    private Integer totalPages;

    // getters and setters ommitted and constructor
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: check whether is image url created ??

Comment: Image url: http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//5N20rQURev5CNDcMjHVUZhpoCNC.jpg

Comment: your movieItem Arraylist has on single item as shown in image but that single item has 20 size. So you pass List<Movies> array to recvyclerview

Comment: `popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), responses);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter);` I have the `responses` with the `ArrayLisy<>()` in the `displayPosters()` method which is then being called in `Subscription`.

Comment: what is the size of responses

Comment: 1. I am pretty lost here. Would you show me how to or a small example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();`

in your onBindViewHolder, so that you don't pass context around.

Also try adding `popularMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your fragment. Do you mind uploading your POJO?

in your adapter

```
public PopularMoviesAdapter(List<Movie> movies) {
    this.movies = movies;
}
```

in your fragment

```
.subscribe(
                        new Action1<MoviesResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(MoviesResponse movies) {
                                responses.add(movies.getResults());
                                popularMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }
                        }
```

Change

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    List<Movies> movies = movieItems.get(position);
    String imageUrl = IntentKeys.MOVIES_POSTER_ENDPOINT + movies.get(position).getPosterPath();
    Log.d(TAG, "Poster URL from the API call: " + imageUrl);
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
    Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);

}
```

Comment: `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
        List<Movies> movies = movieItems.get(position).getResults();
        String imageUrl = IntentKeys.MOVIES_POSTER_ENDPOINT + movies.get(position).getPosterPath();
        Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
    }` `movieItems` has size of 1 and the `getResults()` has the size of 20. No luck, only displays single image

Comment: Assuming you are able to see 20 image urls in your adapter. Can you try moving `popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), responses);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter); ` in onCreateView? And add a null check in your `getItemCount()`? Later add popularMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your Action 1 . Remove the Action 0 from your chain.

Comment: Well, What I meant was, when I debug, the size for the `movies.get(position).getPosterPath()` is 20. I see 20 images in the list for the getResults posters.
And when I do that, I get the json response and all the data in console, but nothing on the view. (I did what you suggested no luck)

Comment: UPDATE `movieItems.size()` is 0, with your suggestion. Without any change to above mentioned details `movieItems.size()` is 1.

Comment: `movieItems.size()` is initially 0 , as you are moving `popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), responses);`  `recyclerView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter);` in onCreateView. Now when you are setting  `responses.add(movies);`  in your Action1 make sure to investigate the response. It should contain 20 List<Movies> results. You POJO suggest you only get 1 Movie Response and n Movies, so you  need to pass List<Movies> to the adapter. That should solve your problem. Size of your MovieResponse would be 1 per call. Also be sure to `popularMoviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123609/discussion-between-krunal-and-ronan).

Answer (score 0):

This is your code to set adapter

```
popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), responses); recyclerView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter);
```

your **ArrayList responses = new ArrayList()** // this is your arraylist which you are providing to adapter

debug and check size of responses that how many records will return i think it has on one object
i think your array is somewhat like this

```
responses [{
    0,{

     } 
}];
```

so passs

```
 popularMoviesAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter(getContext(), responses.get(0).getResults
); recyclerView.setAdapter(popularMoviesAdapter);
```

Comment: `String imageUrl = IntentKeys.MOVIES_POSTER_ENDPOINT + movies.get(position).getPosterPath();` I have that for get the poster path with the position value of 0. And yes, the JSON response is `{"page":1,"results":[{"poster_path":"\/5N20rQURev5CNDcMjHVUZhpoCNC.jpg"` I believe `String imageUrl = IntentKeys.MOVIES_POSTER_ENDPOINT + movieItems.get(0).getPosterPath();` this is getting only one item, not all the items.